# Extracting images from an array

Tags: php, wordpress, simple-html-dom

Hello with the code bellow i am getting some content.
How is possible with php simple html dom to get all the img src?

my code:

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=post-single-content box mark-links]') as $table)
{
$arr44[]=  $table->innertext ;
}
```

div with class post-single-content box mark-links contains text and images

Comment: im sur this other site doesn't mind you stealing their contents

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php if ( $post->post_type == 'data-design' && $post->post_status == 'publish' ) {
    $attachments = get_posts( array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
        'exclude'     => get_post_thumbnail_id()
    ) );

    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
            $class = "post-attachment mime-" . sanitize_title( $attachment->post_mime_type );
            $thumbimg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, 'thumbnail-size', true );
            echo '<li class="' . $class . ' data-design-thumbnail">' . $thumbimg . '</li>';
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This code extract all images from single post content.